# Adding jars inside a jar file to classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a big jar file which contains multiple jars inside the lib folder of the jar file.
If I add the big jar file to classpath, the jars inside the bigjar are not being added to classpath. So, I could not access the classes inside the multiple jar files.

Is there a way for me to reference the classes inside the multiple jars?

Comment: Please show us how you are building your JAR, the tool, command etc.

Comment: You are better off extracting all of the .jar files (or not combining them all in the first place), then running your program with all of them in your classpath.